# include a page selected in URL with $_GET

Tags: php, url

I want to create a page who's including himself the selected page choose in URL (example : `index.php?p=signin` with protection. Can I secure more my page?

I don't secure the text from `$_GET['p']` against injection. I just want to know if its dangerous or not with this method or not ?

```
$grantLevel = [
    'Banned'                => 0 ,
    'Guest'                 => 1 ,
    'Trial'                 => 2 ,
    'Normal'                => 4 ,
    'Premium'               => 8 ,
    'Moderator'             => 16 ,
    'Administrator'         => 32 ,
    'SuperAdministrator'    => 64 
] ;

$pages = [
    'ban'       => $grantLevel['Banned'] ,
    'error'     => $grantLevel['Guest'] ,
    'forbidden' => $grantLevel['Guest'] ,
    'manage'    => $grantLevel['Administrator'] ,
    'signin'    => $grantLevel['Guest'] ,
    'welcome'   => $grantLevel['Guest'] ,
];


$accountLevel = $_SESSION['accountLevel'] ;


if($accountLevel != $grantLevel['Banned']){   

    if(isset($_GET['p'])) {

        if($accountLevel >= $pages[ $_GET['p']]) { 

            $p = $_GET['p'] ;

        } else {

            $p = 'forbidden' ;
        }
    } else { 

        $p = 'error' ;
    }    
} else {

    $p = 'ban' ;
}

require( $p . '.php') ;
```

Comment: If I am a guest, I can simply require the `manage.php` page with `$_GET['p']` as `./manage` instead of `manage`. So, it's not secure.

Comment: Thanks, but i protect this with if($accountLevel >= $pages[ $_GET['p']]) , the page will be forbidden.php,  so it's protected no ?

Comment: No, because `$accountLevel >= $pages[ './manage' ]` is `true`. So, I can include that page.

Comment: You should change `isset($_GET['p'])` to `isset($_GET['p'], $pages[ $_GET['p']])` or else you will get a warning if the page does not exist.

Comment: i need to use a Regex for $_GET so ?

Comment: You don't need to use regex. The `isset` change (in my first comment) would restrict only pages that you specified in your array to be accessed.